# Custom Module's template override not loading initially unless the page is refreshed

Tags: magento2, module, orders, template, overrides

I have the below template override in a custom module, the file path is:

`app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="data">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string"> Vendor_Module::order/create/data.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

This override makes a few changes to the admin page for the creation of an order, when i go through the add order process it initially asks to select or add a customer. once this is done it loads the order page I'm overriding by AJAX, during which it loads the default one found at `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/data.phtml` instead. When I refresh the page, ie with no AJAX being used to load it; it loads fine. I've tried different override methods; clearing caches and different modes (default, development, production).

I also manually installed this plugin https://mageside.com/custom-shipping-price-2.html which seems to have the same issue if that helps.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See extra Space on

```
<argument name="template" xsi:type="string"> Vendor_Module::order/create/data.phtml</argument>
```

extra space between `xsi:type="string">` and `Vendor_Module`.

Remove this.

Also, there are two layout files, you need to define templates for `data.phtml`

1. **sales_order_create_index.xml**
2. **sales_order_create_load_block_data.xml**

**Use below layout for  changes the template instead of argument pattern,**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="data" template="Vendor_Module::order/create/data.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Also, add make `Magento_Sales` as a sequence of `Vendor_Module`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/> <!-- Dependable extension-->
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Note that after this changes you need to run setup upgrade as module sequence is changed.**